# Could not find one or more icon(s) Warning with vuejs application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, icons, warnings, vuetify.js

I am unable to fix the warning:

> Could not find one or more icon(s) {prefix: "far", iconName: "square"} {}" (screenshot attached)
> The warning pops when I change the value of the 'typeOfAreaClass' or select 'safe area' from the "areaClass"

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the menu of v-select with the 'square ' icon:
[image]

I tried installing the font awesome library. It didn't help. One thing I figured out is that the warning occurs when I add the prop "multiple" to the v-select component. If I remove that prop, there is no warning. But it kills the purpose. Does this this help you give a suggestion? My font awesome ions are working fine. Only the v-select prop 'multiple' is creating the warning.

Here is the HTML code

```html
  <v-flex xs12 md4 sm4  >
    <v-select
    class="myfont1 mt-3 pa-0 customDecoration text-xs-right" 
    @change="assignHazGroups"
    :items="typeOfAreaClassItems"
    v-model="typeOfAreaClassSelect"
    style="max-width:170px;"
    dense
    ></v-select> 
  </v-flex>

  <v-flex xs12 md4 sm4  >
    <v-select
    class="myfont1 mt-3 pa-0 mx-0 customDecoration" 
    @change="safeAreaFilter"
    :items="typeOfAreaClassSelect ==='American' ?areaClassAmericanItems:areaClassEuropeanItems"
    v-model="areaClassSelect"
    style="max-width:220px;"
    dense
    ></v-select> 
  </v-flex>

  <v-flex xs12 md4 sm4 class="ma-0 pa-0"
  >
    <v-select
    class="myfont1 mt-3 pa-0 mx-0 customDecoration"
    :items="typeOfAreaClassSelect =='American' ?hazGroupAmericanItems:hazGroupEuropeanItems"
    v-model="hazGroupSelect"
    multiple
    small-chips
    style="max-width:350px;"
    dense
    ></v-select>    

  </v-flex>
```

Here are the array variables

```js
typeOfAreaClassItems:["American","European"],
            areaClassAmericanItems:[
                "Safe Area",
                "Class I, Div 1/Class I, Div 2",
                "Class I, Div 1",
                "Class I, Div 2",
            ],
            areaClassEuropeanItems:[
                "Safe Area",
                "Zone-1/Zone-2",
                "Zone-1",
                "Zone-2"
            ],
            hazGroupAmericanItems:[
                "Group A",
                "Group B",
                "Group C",
                "Group D",
                "NA"
            ],
            hazGroupEuropeanItems:[
                "IIC",
                "IIB+H2",
                "IIB",
                "IIA",
                "NA"
            ],
            eleCertItems:[
                "CSA",
                "UL",
                "ATEX",
                "FM",
                "PESO",
                "JIS (Japan)",
                "GOST (Russia)"
            ],
            
            
  //computed variables          
            typeOfAreaClassSelect:{
                get () {
                    return this.$store.getters.typeOfAreaClassSelect
                },
                set (value) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('setTypeOfAreaClassSelect',{data:value})
                }
            },
            areaClassSelect:{
                get () {
                    return this.$store.getters.areaClassSelect
                },
                set (value) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('setAreaClassSelect',{data:value})
                }
            },
            hazGroupSelect:{
                get () {
                    return this.$store.getters.hazGroupSelect
                },
                set (value) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('setHazGroupSelect',{data:value})
                }
            },
            eleCertSelect:{
                get () {
                    return this.$store.getters.eleCertSelect
                },
                set (value) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('setEleCertSelect',{data:value})
                }
            },
```

And here are the functions

```js
assignHazGroups(){
    if(this.typeOfAreaClassSelect === "American"){
        this.areaClassSelect = "Class I, Div 2"
        this.hazGroupSelect = [
            "Group A",
            "Group B"
        ]
    }
    else{
        this.areaClassSelect = "Zone-2"
        this.hazGroupSelect = [
            "IIB",
            "IIA"
        ]
    }
},
safeAreaFilter(){
    if(this.areaClassSelect === "Safe Area"){
        this.hazGroupSelect = ["NA"]
    }
    else{
        if(this.typeOfAreaClassSelect === "American"){
            this.hazGroupSelect = [
                "Group A",
                "Group B"
            ]
        }
        else{
            this.hazGroupSelect = [
                "IIB",
                "IIA"
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

It appears when I invoke the @change event and call a function. Need to get rid of this warning. The code is all running fine.

Comment: Did you install the font awesome icon pack in your application?

Comment: thanks for the reply. No, I have not installed the  font awesome icon pack.. But my other icons are working fine. It is just this one... And I'm not using any font awesome icons in this html code block..Is it because of the font-awesome stuff that I am getting the warning?

Comment: Yes. `far` is font awesome icon class.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will install the font-awesome library and see if it works..

Comment: I tried installing the font awesome library. It didn't help.
One thing I figured out is that the warning occurs when I add the prop "multiple" to the v-select component. If I remove that prop, there is no warning. But it kills the purpose.  Does this this help you give a suggestion?  My font awesome ions are working fine. Only the v-select prop 'multiple' is creating the warning. Thanks in advance

Comment: The warning pops when I deselect an item from the menu

Comment: fixed it myself as you may see from the answer. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem

Vuetify's `v-simple-checkbox` component uses the icon `checkboxOff` [according to the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-simple-checkbox/#props).

The error that is raised is saying that the icon `far fa-square` cannot be found in Font Awesome. That is because in version 5 the icon is `fas fa-square` [from the documentation](https://fontawesome.com/icons/square).

> [Font Awesomes' FaSvg library assumes that all of the icons are prepended with `fas` which is why the icon `far fa-square` cannot be found.](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#shorthand-that-assumes-a-prefix-of-fas)

### The solution

The fix is to overwrite the `checkboxOff` icon with the correct value.

**setup/vuetify.js**

```js
// All of the import and setup
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

import {library} from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import {fas} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
library.add(fas)

Vue.use(Vuetify);

// The configuration
export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "faSvg",
    values: {
      // The important part!!
      checkboxOff: {
        component: FontAwesomeIcon,
        props: {
          icon: ['fa', 'square'],
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

**main.js**

```js
import App from './App.vue';
import vuetify from './setup/vuetify';

export default new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the iconfont in the vuetify plugin js file.

in the /plugins/vuetify.js file

changed the following code

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'faSvg',
})
```

to this

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md',
})
```

That essentially fixed the icon warning.

Comment: This is replacing the entire font library from Font Awesome to Google's Material Design which in a way fixes the issue but its akin to throwing the baby out with the bath water.

Answer (score 0):

I initially used Daniel Butler's answer, but ran into the same issue with radio buttons. Then I realized that a better fix would be to actually import the regular icon set in Vuetify, the same way the solid icons are being imported.

**setup/vuetify.js**

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);
library.add(fas);
library.add(far);
```

if you haven't already installed the regular icons, you will need to run:

```
$ yarn add @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons -D
// or
$ npm install @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons -D
```

with this change, all of my icons are working correctly without any further custom configuration.